# Borrow pointer of a value which will be moved in a struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

Let's say a `Manager` holds references to a `Designer` and a `Programmer`, but the `Programmer` also has to hold a reference to a `Designer`, in order to ping them whenever they want.

The problem is, by creating both the `Designer` and the `Programmer` in `Manager::new()`, the `&designer` reference doesn't live long enough, since in the following lines, it gets moved inside the `Manager`.

The error is `'designer' does not live long enough`.

```
struct Programmer<'a> {
    designer: &'a Designer,
}

impl<'a> Programmer<'a> {
    pub fn new(designer: &'a Designer) -> Programmer<'a> {
        Programmer { designer: designer }
    }
}

struct Designer {
    iq: u32,
}

impl Designer {
    pub fn new(iq: u32) -> Designer {
        Designer { iq: iq }
    }
}

struct Manager<'a> {
    programmer: Programmer<'a>,
    designer: Designer
}

impl<'a> Manager<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Manager<'a> {
        let designer = Designer::new(42);
        let programmer = Programmer::new(&designer);

        Manager { designer: designer, programmer: programmer }
    }
}

fn main() {
    Manager::new();
}
```

Compilation fails with this message:

```
test.rs:29:47: 29:55 error: `designer` does not live long enough
test.rs:29             let programmer = Programmer::new(&designer);
                                                         ^~~~~~~~
test.rs:27:37: 32:10 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 27:36...
test.rs:27         pub fn new() -> Manager<'a> {
test.rs:28             let designer = Designer::new(42);
test.rs:29             let programmer = Programmer::new(&designer);
test.rs:30
test.rs:31             Manager { designer: designer, programmer: programmer }
test.rs:32         }
test.rs:27:37: 32:10 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 27:36
test.rs:27         pub fn new() -> Manager<'a> {
test.rs:28             let designer = Designer::new(42);
test.rs:29             let programmer = Programmer::new(&designer);
test.rs:30
test.rs:31             Manager { designer: designer, programmer: programmer }
test.rs:32         }
```

How could I fix this problem, without injecting the `Designer` via `Manager::new(&designer)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you know what you're doing, but that doesn't seem like the best design to use with Rust. You say a `Programmer` should hold a reference to a `Designer` in order to ping them, but I imagine that pinging them implies mutating the `Designer` in some way (e.g. imagine some `is_pinged` field on the `Designer`), which you *can't* do via a simple reference. All you can do through a regular, *immutable* reference is read the data or call methods which don't mutate the variable. What's more, so long as you have that reference, the original `Designer` cannot be mutated.

If you do just want to have an immutable reference though, then you can use the [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) type, which provides an immutable reference-counted pointer.

If you want to somehow allow the `Programmer` to send messages to the `Designer` which may or may not trigger mutations on the `Designer`, then you can try using channels. Each `Designer` would store its own [`channel`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/comm/fn.channel.html), and it could have a method which clones the [`Sender`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/comm/struct.Sender.html) end of the channel for an interested `Programmer` to store and use.

Comment: I wasn't implying mutation. I'll try to use `Rc` and see what's going to happen. Thank you for the response. :)

Comment: It worked fine with `Rc`, I think I'm satisfied enough for the time being. Thanks again!